# JQuery is adding a class but not removing it from multiple td elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to make more than one `<td>` field visible or invisible on my screen based on user input and element class. I'm using jquery, html, and javascript.

Basically, I have an HTML table with different fields. I want these fields to have a class of either "Visible", "Visible and Required", or "Invisible". When the user selects an option, it changes the class of that element by removing the previous one and adding the new one. The onload default of these fields should be invisible.

**HTML:**

```
<body onload="ShowTheScreen()">

<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td class="ReasonCode" align="center">
   <span class="FieldLabel">Reason Code</span>
  </td>
  <td class="CostCenter" align="center">
   <span class="FieldLabel">Cost Center</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="ReasonCode" align="center">
   <input type="text" id="ReasonCode" name="ReasonCode" value="1243">
  </td>
  <td class="CostCenter" align="center">
   <input type="text" id="CostCenter" name="CostCenter" value="00123">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="MakeVis" onclick="PopulateTable()">

</body>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function ShowTheScreen(){
  ToggleFieldVisibility(".ReasonCode", 3);
  ToggleFieldVisibility(".CostCenter", 3);
  DisplayFields();
}

function PopulateTable(){
  ToggleFieldVisibility(".ReasonCode", 2);
  ToggleFieldVisibility(".CostCenter", 1);
  DisplayFields();
}

function ToggleFieldVisibility(element, x){
 switch(x){
  case 1:
   $(element).removeClass("Invisible Required").addClass("Visible");
   break;
  case 2:
   $(element).removeClass("Invisible").addClass("Visible Required");
   break;
  case 3:
   $(element).removeClass("Visible Required").addClass("Invisible");
   break;
  default:
   $(element).removeClass("Visible Required").addClass("Invisible");
   break;
 }
 DisplayFields();
}

function DisplayFields(){
 $(".Invisible").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
 $(".Visible").css({"visibility":"visible"});
}
```

*The problem I'm having is this*: When I open the page, the fields get the "Invisible" class added to them as they should be and they become hidden. But when I try and remove the invisible class later and add the visible class, the invisible class is never removed and the visible class is never added: the elements simply retain the classes they had at first, and therefore stay hidden.

I saw previous threads relating to problems with jquery add/removeClass, but none that seemed to help me out. Let me know if you need more info.

UPDATE 1: Thanks for all the replies, everyone! Unfortunately, and I thought this would happen, the code I posted here is a far simplified version of the code I actually have and most of the answers I've received seem to be related to the syntax posted--like the issue with the quotes. I've updated the code to better reflect what I'm really doing. Hopefully this will narrow down what the issue is.

UPDATE 2: I know what I was doing wrong. In my code I have shown here I'm calling ToggleFieldVisibility(".ReasonCode", 2), which works fine. But in my actual code, I was retrieving the number 2 from a SQL call using an outside application, and it was returning it as a string. The "2" would get compared to 2 in the switch (or "1" to 1 and "3" to 3) and always go to default, so that's why those fields always came up invisible. Hah!

Comment: `onclick="ToggleFieldVisibility(".ReasonCode", 1)>` is wrong. Try `onclick="ToggleFieldVisibility('.ReasonCode', 1)">`
And why are you manually setting the visibility of elements by class? Why not just use the css class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your inline `onClick` handlers. As you currently have them, you are using quotation marks as both attribute delimiters and to wrap your strings; this is going to cause your attribute to be truncated as `ToggleFieldVisibility("` and your function will not run.

Try:

```
<input type="button" value="MakeVis" onclick="ToggleFieldVisibility('.ReasonCode', 1)">
<input type="button" value="MakeVisReq" onclick="ToggleFieldVisibility('.ReasonCode', 2)">
<input type="button" value="MakeInVis" onclick="ToggleFieldVisibility('.ReasonCode', 3)">
```

If you need to use `"`s for some reason, you can always escape them with a \: `(\".ReasonCode\"...`

Comment: Saw that, wasn't sure if that was the entire issue though.

Answer (score 1):

A quick guess, in calling the `DisplayFields()` function at the end, it adds css to the element in the form of an inline style tag. Try running a `.removeAttr("style")` right after doing the `removeClass()`

The code:

jquery:

```
function ToggleFieldVisibility(element, x){
            //alert("Hello");
            switch(x){
                case 1:
                    $(element).removeClass("Invisible Required").removeAttr("style").addClass("Visible");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $(element).removeClass("Invisible").removeAttr("style").addClass("Visible Required");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $(element).removeClass("Visible Required").removeAttr("style").addClass("Invisible");
                    break;
                default:
                    $(element).removeClass("Visible Required").removeAttr("style").addClass("Invisible");
                    break;
                }
            DisplayFields();
        }

        function DisplayFields(){
            $(".Invisible").css({"visibility":"hidden"});
            $(".Visible").css({"visibility":"visible"});
        }
```

html:

```
<body onload="ToggleFieldVisibility('.ReasonCode .CostCenter', 3)">
<table border="1">
 <tr>
  <td class="ReasonCode" align="center">
   <span class="FieldLabel">Reason Code</span>
  </td>
  <td class="CostCenter" align="center">
   <span class="FieldLabel">Cost Center</span>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td class="ReasonCode" align="center">
   <input type="text" id="ReasonCode" name="ReasonCode" value="1243">
  </td>
  <td class="CostCenter" align="center">
   <input type="text" id="CostCenter" name="CostCenter" value="00123">
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>

<input type="button" value="MakeVis" onclick="ToggleFieldVisibility('.ReasonCode', 1)" />
<input type="button" value="MakeVisReq" onclick="ToggleFieldVisibility('.ReasonCode', 2)" />
<input type="button" value="MakeInVis" onclick="ToggleFieldVisibility('.ReasonCode', 3)" />

</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :)! Unfortunately, that didn't remove the "Invisible" class from those fields. I put an alert(element id prevclass newclass); statement at the end of ToggleFieldVisibility() before the DisplayFields() call, and I could see the fields being added back to the screen as they had their styles removed, but then they would disappear again once DisplayFields() was called because they still had the class of "Invisible".

Comment: @LCIII Please try the code I posted, as that works properly for me.